# pyqt5 Is there a more elegant way of altering the functionality of a button, depending on what checkboxes are checked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm a newbie, playing around with PyQT5 module and learning how to make a GUI for my small program.

I've made a small gui with 3 checkboxes and a button, the functionality of which the checkboxes alter.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
#Checkboxes and button logic
def stateChanged(self):
    if self.GetErrorsBox.isChecked() and self.GetSpecsBox.isChecked() and self.GetConfigBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getErrors())
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.copyConfig())
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getSpecs())

    elif self.GetErrorsBox.isChecked() and self.GetSpecsBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getSpecs())
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getErrors())

    elif self.GetErrorsBox.isChecked() and self.GetConfigBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getErrors())
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getSpecs())

    elif self.GetSpecsBox.isChecked() and self.GetConfigBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.copyConfig())
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getSpecs())

    elif self.GetSpecsBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getSpecs())

    elif self.GetErrorsBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getErrors())

    elif self.GetConfigBox.isChecked():
        self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.copyConfig())
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to refactor all these IFs and ELIFs into something more readable?

I may add a yet another checkbox in the future, so I *really* don't want to keep adding IFs and ELIFs. I don't want to be the next yandev, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all the `elif`, just do:

```
if self.GetSpecsBox.isChecked():
    self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getSpecs())

if self.GetErrorsBox.isChecked():
    self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.getErrors())

if self.GetConfigBox.isChecked():
    self.execButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.copyConfig())
```